# Hazelcast partition count

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have multiple  Hazelcast maps that I load eagerly. The data in these maps varies greatly in size. I wanted to know if I could change the partition count per map rather than having common configuration for all maps.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, no. Partition count is a cluster-wide setting.

It applies to all `DistributedObject` types, not just maps.